# Binding random colors to items of listbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I want to generate different colors' item in a listbox. For example - rectangle of different colors in every item. I am not able to do so.
So far I have created a class like this

```
public class RandomColorGenerator
{
    public Color randomBrush { get; set; }
    private static Random randomColor = new Random();
    private static uint[] uintColors =
    { 
        0xFF34AADC,0xFFFF2D55,0xFF007AFF,0xFFFF9500,0xFF4CD964,
        0xFFFFCC00,0xFF5856D6,0xFFFF3B30,0xFFFF4981,0xFFFF3A2D
    };

    public RandomColorGenerator()
    {
        randomBrush = generateRandomColor();
    }

    private static Color ConvertColor(uint uintCol)
    {
        byte A = (byte)((uintCol & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
        byte R = (byte)((uintCol & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
        byte G = (byte)((uintCol & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
        byte B = (byte)((uintCol & 0x000000FF) >> 0); 
        return Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B); ;
    }

    public static Color generateRandomColor()
    {
        return ConvertColor(uintColors[randomColor.Next(0, 9)]);
    }
}
```

and in XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="TestListBox"  >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Margin="10" Height="100" Width="400" >
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding randomBrush, 
                                             Source={StaticResource colorgenerate}}">
                    </SolidColorBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

After doing all this I get the result like this -

[image: SampleImage1]

After relaunching the app, I get this

[image: SampleImage2]

Though I am getting random colors whenever I run the app. But one color is applied to all the rectangles.

I don't know how to get the desired result. 
I want something like this -

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share as the code where you call the code to bind the colors to listbox?? The problem lies there I believe

Comment: Binding takes place in XAML (shown above). I am a noob here in Windows Phone Development.

Comment: Could you post the resource 'colorgenerate' you're binding to?

Comment: @Code4A You really need to read a book or some tutorials about WP, XAML, MVVM and bindings. These things are all very important if you plan to be doing more WP/WPF development. I think that's the important lesson here. :)

Comment: @yasen Well, I am about to get some training in C# and ASP.Net this summer. After that, I will definitely try MVVM. I have heard so much about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that you generate RabdomBrush only when you create class RandomColorGenerator.

You should generate new RandomBrush each time when you call it. Kinda like this:

```
public class RandomColorGenerator
{
  public Color randomBrush { 

    get {return generateRandomColor(); }

}
....
```

Comment: This was all about binding random colors. In this method, sometimes I get same color for consecutive rectangles (that's obvious for random generation of colors). How can I achieve something like this (second screenshot) - [Poki App Screeshot](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/poki/2532ff45-aa3f-4aba-a266-ed7ec71d47bd)
It has different colors' ring with no consecutive rings having the same color.

Comment: Well, just change your generateRandomColor() method. Keep already generated random values in a list. And on each next random check new value with list to understand do you have already this color or not.

Comment: @Code4A How about just storing the index of the color to return and every time you return a color, increment the index. It would be a loop, not completely random, but is that a problem? You can of course shuffle the numbers at the beginning to make it more random.

Answer (score 1):

All the your code is ready. just do these changes in your code.

Your listbox xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="TestListBox">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Rectangle Margin="10" Height="100" Width="400" >
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding}">
                </SolidColorBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

In your page constructor. add following code

```
 List<RandomColorGenerator> list = new List<RandomColorGenerator>();
        list.Add(new RandomColorGenerator());
        list.Add(new RandomColorGenerator());
        list.Add(new RandomColorGenerator());
        list.Add(new RandomColorGenerator());
        list.Add(new RandomColorGenerator());
        list.Add(new RandomColorGenerator());
        TestListBox.ItemsSource = list;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: In this method, sometimes I get same color for consecutive rectangles (that's obvious for random generation of colors). How can I achieve something like this (second screenshot) - [Poki App Screeshot](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/poki/2532ff45-aa3f-4aba-a266-ed7ec71d47bd)
It has different colors' ring with no consecutive rings having the same color.

Comment: see my answer for no repeat

Answer (score 1):

For your question of no repeat I have updated your class see the class below. now your colors will not be repeated. But make sure that you do not add more than 10 colors.

```
public class RandomColorGenerator
{
    private static List<int> addedIndex = new List<int>();
    public Color randomBrush { get { return generateRandomColor(); } }
    private static Random randomColor = new Random();
    private static uint[] uintColors =
    { 
        0xFF34AADC,0xFFFF2D55,0xFF007AFF,0xFFFF9500,0xFF4CD964,
        0xFFFFCC00,0xFF5856D6,0xFFFF3B30,0xFFFF4981,0xFFFF3A2D
    };

    private static Color ConvertColor(uint uintCol)
    {
        byte A = (byte)((uintCol & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
        byte R = (byte)((uintCol & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
        byte G = (byte)((uintCol & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
        byte B = (byte)((uintCol & 0x000000FF) >> 0);
        return Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B); ;
    }

    public static Color generateRandomColor()
    {
        int random = randomColor.Next(0, 9);
        if (addedIndex.Count < 9)
        {
            while (addedIndex.Contains(random))
            {
                random = randomColor.Next(0, 9);
            }
            addedIndex.Add(random);
        }
        return ConvertColor(uintColors[random]);
    }
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating things. Why not just loop through them... and if you need them to be random, shuffle them when you reach the end and reset.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to assign a collection of Color to ListBox, something like as given below in the code snippet below:

In Xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="TestListBox" ItemSource={Binding ColorList}>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Margin="10" Height="100" Width="400" >
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding}">
                    </SolidColorBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
</ListBox>
```

In View Model:

```
public class RandomColorGeneratorViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private List<Color> _colorList;
    public List<Color> ColorList
    {
        get { return _colorList; }
        set { _colorList = value; }
    }
}
```

In Window/UserControl contructor, add this line:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new RandomColorGeneratorViewModel();
}
```

Now the best way to generate the random colors is by generating Red, Green, Blue value in integer and convert them to Hex and assign to this collection.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know how to use MVVM and I have no ViewModel in my project.

Comment: Its simple and very helpful to use WPF, let me publish ViewModel example also that will ease of your life to do the needful.

Comment: Sorry, I got the answer. I will definitely try it in your way.